# Concurrently execute tests within same JVM

Tags: java, maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to execute tests concurrently within the same JVM via surefire. My surefire config looks like below

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
  <configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
      <ut.forkNumber>$${surefire.forkNumber}</ut.forkNumber>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
    <!--These values are chosen experimentally-->
    <argLine>
      -Xms512m -Xmx512m
      -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m
      -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
      -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError @{argLine}
    </argLine>
    <parallel>classes</parallel>
    <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

On executing the below command

```
mvn test -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=true
```

I am observing that all my test classes are being executed in `ThreadStreamConsumer`

```
[ThreadedStreamConsumer] [INFO] Running com.spotnana.servicetests.profile.ProfileCreatePersonalUserTest
...
[ThreadedStreamConsumer] [INFO] Running com.spotnana.servicetests.profile.PlanServiceTest
```

Can someone let me know what am I doing wrong which is causing all test classes to execute in a single thread?

- JUnit Version 5.9.2
- Java 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [maven mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread/nh9j45kmtwc796s5b0jygtftx3sorr5x) and also by @armandino in one of the answer, I decided to use JUnit5 to execute tests in parallel by placing the below, `junit-platform.properties` file in `src/test/resources` folder

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=4
# Configuration parameters to execute top-level classes in parallel but methods in same thread
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=same_thread
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default=concurrent
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you're asking, but I remember having problems trying to configure parallel test execution with the `surefire` plugin, and using the `failsafe` plugin for unit tests instead:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <configurationParameters>
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
            </configurationParameters>
        </properties>
        <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/</testSourceDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You might have more luck with a more recent version of the `surefire` plugin (the configuration should be very similar to the above).

Here's some documentation that might be helpful:

- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution
- https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

Comment: The above configuration is using junit5 to execute the tests in parallel. Running tests in parallel using junit5 is still an [experimental](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.9.2/user-guide/index.html) feature (even though it is like this for a long time), so I was trying to execute the tests concurrently as mentioned in [surefire doc](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html#parallel-test-execution). I was suggested to use Junit5 in maven mailing list. Maybe there is some issue in surefire for concurrent executing in the same jvm.

Comment: I started using `junit-platform.properties` but it is messing up the surefire xml reporting. Discussed in the [maven mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread/6k10kmxzz75rz8mqn3pl1ltvfltw87m9)